# How to detect if Spring Validation passed?

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation

I am trying to use Spring 3.0 validations using annotations.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

My code looks like in the documentation:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processFoo(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }

}

public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    /**
     * This Validator validates just Person instances
     */
   public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return Person.class.equals(clazz);
  }

public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
}
```

}

How do I tell in my RequestMapping method if the validation passed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Aah ... that was trivial ... just figured out I have a [BindingResult](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) parameter in my RequestMapping which has a hasErrors() method.